# how to sort a mongodb database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I got a collection that looks like,

```
[
  {"_id":"543a631d525dc7684bb730e3","word":"sda","description":"dsa"},
  {"_id":"543a634e525dc7684bb730e4","word":"dsa","description":"dasda"},
  {"_id":"543a6886525dc7684bb730e5","word":"sadas","description":"asaaa"}
]
```

I have trouble sorting the list by alphabetical order,
what I've tried now is-

```
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    db.collection('userlist').find().sort({ word: 1 })
    db.collection('userlist').find().toArray(function (err, items) {
        res.json(items);
    });
});
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can sort this list by word?

Comment: fixed it:     router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    db.collection('userlist').find({}, { sort:[['word',1]]}).toArray(function (err, items){
        res.json(items);
    });
});

Answer (score 1):

This is not how it will work, if you have any background from programming then you should know that the first `db...find()` will return the `data (cursor)` you want, but you are not storing that data in any variable, and in your second `db....find()` you are not applying the `sort`.

So, i know you have found the answer yourself, but still you can also use something like this,

```
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
    db.collection('userlist').find().sort({ word: 1 }).toArray(function (err, items) {
        res.json(items);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mongoose, you can sort as follows:

```
router.route('/userlist')

// CREATE ROUTE FOR USERLIST
// =========================
.get(function(req, res) {

  // SEND THE USERLIST AFTER SORTING THEM OUT IN ALPHABETICAL ORDER
  Snippets.find().sort({time: -1}).exec(function(err, items) {
    res.json(items);
  })
})
```